# How to filter a tableview

Tags: java, javafx, filter, tableview

I have a tableview to filter. I am unable to work both updating tableview and filter. In one hand When I declare an observableList and initiate as observalist, filtering is working but when I make a new insert old data plus new ones are shown. I do not know if I explain well. And in the other hand if I initiate inside my function populating the tabelview, filtering is not working.
Is this code is correct???????

Better maybe to show the code

```
public class addBonPageController implements Initializable {

private ObservableList<Bon> dataBonList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
FilteredList<Bon> filter = new FilteredList<>(dataBonList, e -> true);

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
bonTableView();}
```

}

Comment: Your question isn't very clear about the problem you are facing. Please try to improve your question and update the sample to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry. For me also it was not clear. I wondering how to clearly to expose my problem.

Comment: I am stucking on how to filter a tableview. The way currently the code is having a problem

Comment: *"In one hand When I declare an observableList and initiate as observalist, filtering is working but when I make a new insert old data plus new ones are shown."* Is this not what you want? Shouldn't all the data be shown?

Comment: currently data is shown correctly in the tableview. The problem is when I insert new row of data and click on submit buttion, data is doubling in the tableview. old row + old row with the new row. Hope I explained sorry otherwise

Comment: “Is this code correct”. Yes: the code you have posted appears to be correct.

Comment: But data is double in tableview. If only I do not initialize dataBonList variable data will be correct.